# How to prevent Paho to send an ACK after processing a message from the broker?

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I am working on a project with Paho on Java. Messages received from the broker are sent to an API that processes them, but this process might fail or take to long. I would like to take advantage of MQTT acknowledgement system and, in such cases, prevent the ACK to be sent so the broker resends the same message after a while. Is this possible with Paho?

Regards.

Comment: This is a bad idea, the QOS handshakes are there to ensure delivery happens properly not to be a indicator of some other process completing. If you need to signal the end process has finished include a message id in the payload and send a new message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee that this will work. Message retries are implementation specific.

[Section 4.4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/errata01/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc442180916) of the MQTT v3.1.1 spec states

> When a Client reconnects with CleanSession set to 0, both the Client
>   and Server MUST re-send any unacknowledged PUBLISH Packets (where QoS
>   0) and PUBREL Packets using their original Packet Identifiers [MQTT-4.4.0-1]. **This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server
>   is REQUIRED to redeliver messages.**

The emphasis is mine.

The trend I've seen is for implementations to remove message retries except for when reconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

I facing the same situation, and found it's been a built-in feature of the Java phho mqtt client.

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/mqttv5/client/IMqttAsyncClient.java#L823

Here is a demo code to show how to use it.

```
#enable manual ack
client.setManualAcks(true);

#send ack after message processed
client.messageArrivedComplete(messageId, qos);
```